# How to increment a value every loop, then have a function run on the third loop?

Tags: arduino

I've looked through other threads here, but none seems to answer such a basic question.

I want my code to have a variable by the name of loops, and I want it to increment once every loop, and on my third loop I want it to do:

```cpp
digitalWrite(ledPinBLUE, HIGH); // skrur på LED lyset - BLÅ
delay(500); // 750 milli sek delay.
digitalWrite(ledPinBLUE, LOW); // skrur av LED lyset - BLÅ
delay(500); // 750 milli sek delay.
```

And I want all of this to happen independently of the rest of my code. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You increment a counter on every loop and when it reaches 3, you reset it to 0 and run the function.

```cpp
some_counter++
if (some_counter == 3) {
    some_counter = 0;
    some_function()
}
```